# How to download fbsdk v5?

Tags: facebook, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to **download fbsdk v5** from [facebook sdk downloads.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads) Here it *refers to* [this github page](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk) for download. And from the github page it *refers back to* the previous same page [facebook sdk downloads.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads)

It's unending loops of references. 
**Can someone help me with a link to the download of fbsdk v5 directly?**

Comment: The mere fact that it _refers back_ doesn’t mean you have to _click_ on such links, and thereby go in circles on your own volition :-) You can get the code simply via the “Clone or Download” button on the github page …

Comment: There were no frameworks (login, share etc) on github v5 docs and i end up using fbsdk using cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

You can download by clicking the button `clone or download` simply

[image]

If you want to use facebook-sdk in your react-native project i would highly recommend to use [react-native-fbsdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdk) package by npm instead of download and use.